# MariaDB or MySQL @@SESSION.tx_read_only always returns 0

Tags: mysql, mariadb, transaction

I'm trying to figure out possible "read only" transaction setup leak between pooled connections (on the same physical connection) in Java application which lead me to a question "How can I find out what the current transaction read-only-ness really is?"

I'm using versions `10.0.28-MariaDB-wsrep` and `5.7.31-0ubuntu0.18.04.1` and whatever I do, when I issue the statement:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.tx_read_only, @@SESSION.tx_read_only;
```

It always returns 0 for both values. (I've tried also the non-deprecated variable on MySql, the same result.)

I've read [how to start transaction](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/start-transaction/) for [both databases](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html) and even when I get the error `Cannot execute statement in a READ ONLY transaction.` which is haunting me in the application, the `tx_read_only` is still 0.

I tried the following in IDEA SQL console:

- turn of auto-commit
- `set TRANSACTION READ ONLY;`
- `START TRANSACTION;`
- `INSERT ...` - *Originally:* no problem on MySQL, failed on MariaDB, I understand the reason, it is documented. *EDIT:* I tried [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=2af4b2c222061b0e20053f0629c245eb) and [this one](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b57987693f87a9ab76779d5bb911d743) and both fail on the first INSERT. My previous experience might have been caused by unclear session.
- start TRANSACTION READ ONLY; -- EDIT: probably not relevant now.
- `INSERT ...` - ended with `Cannot execute statement in a READ ONLY transaction.` on both DBs.

Any step of the way, `tx_read_only` was always 0. What may be the problem? What is the right way to ask the DB whether INSERT is allowed before actually trying to do it?

Comment: I agree, looks like a bug, so I wrote a [bug report MDEV-23579](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-23579). Generally in SQL however you don't ask first, you do and the catch errors. It tends to avoid race conditions though this is a little different in that respect.

Comment: 5.7.26 and 8.0.16 also return 0 (for whichever VARIABLE they allow).

Comment: @danblack I agree about catching errors for normal application run, this was for diagnostic purposes when we had a suspected "read-only-ness" leak from one pooled connection to the next (on the same physical one) due to `SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY` usage that (unexpectedly for us) has different semantics on MariaDB than on MySQL. Also thank you for bug report, I wasn't that far to be sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: Apart from the change of variable name, [mariadb-10.4](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=dba3e835f4010e9e0855ba356530e655),  and [mysql-8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6fed7c618dee71309f283a8af5ffc757) appear to have the same results as does [mysql-5.7.29](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6fed7c618dee71309f283a8af5ffc757).

Comment: @danblack You're right, I don't know what happened in my previous tests. Seems like I messed up something on that MySQL session that the insert in the original post worked. I'll edit the post and next time use something like dbfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another [fiddle test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=036c02b007bb0b92d0aac706ded6f5e8)

So both MariaDB  on `tx_read_only` and mysql on `transaction_read_only` have the session variable set to the current session value. The "next transaction access mode" remains hidden.

Catching insert errors seems like the only option.

Comment: Aha, I understand a bit better now. But for MariaDB https://mariadb.com/kb/en/start-transaction/ states that `SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY` "can also be specified in the SET TRANSACTION statement, in which case the specified mode is valid for all sessions, or for all subsequent transaction used by the current session." I tried this fiddle
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=ad136f9644a7435ca9dfcc4f027f7b20
but only "SET TRANSACTION SESSION" changes the variable. Is it right?

Comment: You cannot observe the result of `set transaction read_only` in using the system variables, only its [effect](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=3667e833ff887d4724aaae95d52c734a). `set transaction read_only` however is only valid for the next transaction as the fiddle also shows. Yes the document needs to be clarified.

Comment: I see, I tried [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=bb37cf750289b2a89e196f5ae855337a) with two following `START TRANSACTION` and clearly without `SESSION` in `SET TRANSACTION` it really works the second time. I had a different experience based on very obscure situation described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63580806/658826), when I read JDBC connection metadata in the first transaction it somehow stayed read only for the next transaction - so I looked for reasons why in the wrong places.

Comment: Ad documentation, when I don't look for wrong answers, it actually links [SET TRANSACTION](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-transaction/) page, where everything is clear. I'm sorry for the confusion and thanks again for the clarification.